# Is ftol and gtol needed in scipy.optimize.minimize is it proper to give it a very low value?

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, floating-point, scipy-optimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

I am using the bounded limited memory BFGS optimizer to minimize the value of a black box function. I have simulated randomly many input parameter combinations and realized that the `ftol` and `gtol` parameter is only in the way, and it doesn't contribute anything to decreasing the value of my function (there is a positive correlation between the outputs and the random inputs for `ftol` and `gtol`, so the smaller the better). So I set both to `1E-18` and focused on configuring the other parameters, thus the exit message `CONVERGENCE: REL_REDUCTION_OF_F <= FACTR*EPSMCH` meaning that the entire optimization depended on the correct value for `eps` I guess.

Then I set both `ftol` and `gtol` to `1E-20` to not stand in the way, but then I started getting sub-optimal results.

So my optimizer is:

```
scipy.optimize.minimize(function, x0=guess.flatten(), method='L-BFGS-B', bounds=bounds, options={ 'maxcor': maxcor, 'ftol': 1E-20, 'gtol': 1E-20, 'eps': eps, 'maxfun': maxrounds, 'maxiter': maxrounds, 'maxls': maxls})
```

So I set it to `1E-20` and the other values are fed randomly. The average output for a bigger sample is smaller with `1E-20` than with `1E-18`, I don't understand why, they are supposed to be very small numbers that are negligible. I also started getting exit messages like `CONVERGENCE: NORM OF PROJECTED GRADIENT <= PGTOL` which I don't know how it was possible for such a small tolerance.
So I have the following questions:

1) Is it worth setting `ftol` and `gtol` to such low values as `1E-20`?

2) Should I set `tol` the (external tolerance value) if `ftol` and `gtol` is already set? I don't want it to exit ahead of time. Or does `tol` as an exit threshold get disabled if `gtol` and `ftol` is enabled?

3) Is it possible that Scipy, Numpy or Python3 itself can't handle floating point values with 20 decimals. I noticed Python mostly prints 18 digits for floats, so could the problem be that I put too many digits. If so then what is the maximum number of digits handled by scipy.optimize? (Scipy v1.4.1 | Numpy v1.18.1 | Python 3.5.3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tolerance that you are setting is not really achievable due to round-off errors. You can read [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) more about the floating point precision in Python. You should choose a small, but sensible number for gtol and ftol, usually 1e-6 - 1e-8 works.